# How to delete a dictionary based on a key inside its nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have the following data structure:

```
data = [{"match_id":1, "players":[{"player_name":"Tom", "won":True},
                                  {"player_name":"Anna", "won":False}]}, 
        {"match_id":2, "players":[{"player_name":"Tom", "won":None},
                                  {"player_name":"Fred", "won":None}]}]
```

**My goal is to define a function that removes the matches where no player has won** `(i.e. "won":None)`.

For the given example above, the output should look like this:

```
data = [{"match_id":1, "players":[{"player_name":"Tom", "won":True},
                                  {"player_name":"Anna", "won":False}]}]
```

---

I have tried the following approach:

```
def delete_None(data):
result = []
for match in data:
    for players in match['players']:
        if players['won'] == None:
            del data_nt[match]
return result
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a259efc7b5fa> in <module>
----> 1 data_nt_nn = delete_None(data)

<ipython-input-20-68ffe18e4fff> in delete_None(data_nt)
      4         for players in match['players']:
      5             if players['won'] == None:
----> 6                 del data_nt[match]
      7     return result
      8 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in just one line:

```
data = [d for d in data if not all(p['won'] is None for p in d['players'])]
```

---

Also this will be helpful to get the algorithm

```
key_to_removes = [] 
for i,d in enumerate(data): 
    if all(p['won'] is None for p in d['players']): 
        key_to_removes.append(i)
```

then `key_to_removes` will be

```
[1]
```

then you can remove indexes from your data.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some benefit to having the data structured as it is, consider creating a new object. When looping through, start by figuring out how to access the values you need. For example, to access the value of 'won' for 'Tom' in match_id '1', you would use

```
data[0]['players'][0]['won']
```

You can loop through the two lists in your object as needed.

Answer (score 1):

remove from the list and break to exit loop early when found.

```
result = []
for match in data:
    for players in match['players']:
        if players['won'] == None:
            data.remove(match)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a list comprehension to filter out the matches where all players have a `"won": None` value:

```
data = [{"match_id": 1, "players": [{"player_name": "Tom", "won": True},
                                    {"player_name": "Anna", "won": False}]},
        {"match_id": 2, "players": [{"player_name": "Tom", "won": None},
                                    {"player_name": "Fred", "won": None}]}]


print([match 
       for match in data 
       if all(player.get('won') is not None for player in match.get('players'))])
```

Output:

```
[{'match_id': 1, 'players': [{'player_name': 'Tom', 'won': True}, {'player_name': 'Anna', 'won': False}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
[ d for d in data if bool([player for player in d["players"] if player["won"] is not None])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `filter`.

For example:

```py
#Return item if "None" does not exist
def filter_none_element(d):
    won_list = [ player.get('won') for player in d.get('players')]
    return None not in won_list


filtered_data = list(filter(filter_none_element, data))
print('{}'.format(filtered_data))
```